# Swift 3 Trying to pass audio path/audio file, to audio player VC

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am new to swift and programming in general. When a cell is pressed I want to segue into a audio player view and play selected audio. For now i only got one audio playing, it doesn't matter what cell is selected. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var pictures = ["AlbertEinstein.jpg","dreamBig.jpg", "LionFearless.jpg", "MLK.jpg"]
    var names = ["Einstein", "DreamBig", "LionFearless", "MartinLutherKing",]

    let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Music", ofType: "mp3")
    let newAudioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AchievingAnythingYouWant", ofType: "m4a")

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.tittleLabel!.text = names[indexPath.row]
        cell.pictureImage.image = UIImage(named: pictures[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            let detailVC = segue.destination as! PlayerViewController
            let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            //path to audio file
            let row = newAudioPath
            detailVC.sendData1 = row!

            let row2 = audioPath
            //variable in deatilVC to hold audio
            detailVC.sendData2 = row2!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "For now i only got one audio playing, it doesn't matter what cell is selected" That makes perfect sense, since `audioPath` (and `newAudioPath`) never changes.

Comment: So do you know how to change that and let different songs play for selected cells?

Comment: Yes, I do. And so do you, since Donovan King's answer tells you.

Comment: Ok, I will try and figure it out... Thanks

Comment: Well, think about it. If you want every row of the table to correspond to a different song, then you need to make that happen. Right now you are not making it happen. Somewhere you would need an array of songs (i.e. song file paths), to correspond to your array of names and your array of pictures. But you have no such array.

Comment: Got it! So i should create an array with all the song file path? Can you please show me how to do that, within this same class?

Comment: No, I'm not going to write your code for you. Especially since Donovan King has in fact already done that. If you're going to ask a question, don't you think you should read the answer?

Comment: I did, but didnt fully understand everything he stated. As I said, I am new to swift and just started learning swift. Thanks for your help, anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So currently the "model" you're using to back your tableview cells only contains the names of the songs. The proper way to do this would be to create a new class that will server as your model object.

For example:

```
class SongModel {
    let name: String
    let imagePath: String
    let audioPath: String

    init(name: String, imagePath: String, audioPath: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.imagePath = imagePath
        self.audioPath = audioPath
    }
}
```

Then you can use instances of that class to back your TableViewController:

```
// Instead of:
// var names = ["Einstein", "DreamBig", "LionFearless", "MartinLutherKing"]    

var model = [SongModel]()
```

Then in `viewDidLoad()` you can load the model array with SongModel instances. This is a very simple model example.

Now in `prepareFor(Segue:_, Sender:_)`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

    let detailVC = segue.destination as! PlayerViewController

    let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        // Pass reference to selected model object (youll have to add 
        // the property to the detailVC)
        detailVC.selectedSong = model[myIndexPath.row]
        // now your detail vc will have access to the model
    }
}
```

I'd also encourage you to use if-let or guard statements for unwrapping in stead of force unwrapping with the `optionalValue!`. So like this:

```
if let detailVC = segue.destination as? PlayerViewController {
   if let myIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
      detailVC.selectedSong = model[myIndexPath.row]
   }
}
```

Mind the `as?` that's an optional unwrap that when combined with an if-let or guard-else allows the unwrap to fail without crashing your app.

You'll also have to adjust your other tableview delegate/datasource methods to account for the new model.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Donovan King, but that went over my head. Only understood, some of what you mentioned.

Comment: @IamWayne I'm more than happy to help you understand the above code. What specifically did you have trouble understanding?